# How to encode words in a list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, encoding, text-processing

I have a dictionary where I have each word as a key and a corresponding integer value, such as :

```
 {'me': 41, 'are': 21, 'the': 0}
```

I have a data frame with a column of lists of words that are already tokenized, such as :

```
['I', 'liked', 'the', 'color', 'of', 'this', 'top']
['Just', 'grabbed', 'this', 'today', 'great', 'find']
```

How can I encode each of these words into their corresponding values from the dictionary. For example:

```
[56, 78, 5, 1197, 556, 991, 40]
```

Comment: ID system. I want each word to be represented by an integer as defined in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using a dictionary and list

The following uses a dictionary (`final_dictionary`) to determine the id's of the words.  This is great if you have a preset dictionary of id's.

```
def encode_tokens(tokens):
    encoded_tokens = tokens[:]
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        if token in final_dictionary:
            encoded_tokens[i] = final_dictionary[token]
    return encoded_tokens

print(encode_tokens(tokens))
```

## Adding and maintaining id's

If you are dynamically assigning id's I would implement a class to do so (see bellow).  If you, however, have a dictionary of id's that you have already defined ahead of time, you can pass in the keyword argument `di`:

```
token_words_1 = ['I', 'liked', 'the', 'color', 'of', 'this', 'top']
token_words_2 = ['I', 'liked', 'to', 'test', 'repeat', 'words']

class AutoId:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.di = kwargs.get("di", {})
        self.loc = 0
    def get(self, value):
        if value not in self.di:
            self.di[value] = self.loc
            self.loc += 1
        return self.di[value]
    def get_list(self, li):
        return [*map(self.get, li)]

encoding = AutoId()
print(encoding.get_list(token_words_1))
print(encoding.get_list(token_words_2))
```

Comment: @BiBi The original poster liked it and some people find it easier to understand concise logic structures instead of Python's plithera of built-ins.  To each their own.

Comment: I would agree if it'd imply using some obscure functionality of the language, but list comprehension is, in my opinion, at the core of python and improves readability :).

Comment: Yes the answer above is easy to comprehend and I prefer it's implementation as a function.

Answer (score 5):

What about doing

```
word2key = {'me': 41, 'are': 21, 'the': 0}
words = ['Just', 'grabbed', 'this', 'today', 'great', 'find']
default = 'unknown'
output = [word2key.get(x, default) for x in words]
```

You might want to use `x.lower()` if you want `'Just'` and `'just'` to be mapped to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your dict is in a variable named `d` and your list is named `l`:

```
d = {'me': 41, 'are': 21, 'the': 0}
l = ['I', 'liked', 'the', 'color', 'of', 'this', 'top']

print(l)
c = 0
while c < len(l):
    try:
        l[c] = d[l[c]]
    except:
        l[c] = None
    c += 1

print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

# d = {'me': 41, 'are': 21, 'the': 0}
l1 = ['I', 'liked', 'the', 'color', 'of', 'this', 'top']
l2 = ['Just', 'grabbed', 'this', 'today', 'great', 'find']

# This is just for data generation for the sake of a complete example.
# Use your already given d here instead.
d = {k: np.random.randint(10) for k in chain(l1, l2)}
print(d)

l1_d = [d.get(k, 0) for k in l1]  # <- this is the actual command you need
print(l1_d)

l2_d = [d.get(k, 0) for k in l2]
print(l2_d)
```

Outcome:

```
{'I': 3, 'liked': 3, 'the': 8, 'color': 7, 'of': 3, 'this': 5,
 'top': 3, 'Just': 6, 'grabbed': 0, 'today': 0, 'great': 7, 'find': 0}
[3, 3, 8, 7, 3, 5, 3]
[6, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0]
```